# twilio call from browser to phone

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I am trying twilio to make phone calls from my browser to mobile numbers but unsuccessful. Following are the steps i followed:

1. Downloaded twilio-php api:
   https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php
2. Downloaded twilio browser-phone code:
   https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/twilio-client-browser-soft-phone
3. Created a twilio account, selected a number and updated this code:
   https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8eed141b1b4214110592

Now when i dial any real phone number, i get the message:
"..Configure your numbers voice url to change this message..." and "Call ended".

Appreciate clear guidance on how to get this work (call from browser to a real number).

Comment: Can you help me out how you develop this to make calls from browsers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a TwiML app and provide the voice url over there.
Create a php file and provide the url in the twiml app and place the twiml app sid to your browser phone code.

```
$token->allowClientOutgoing('AP19471819473945b0d234ba2007a351c4'); //twiml appsid
```

and this php code in voice url

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
?>
<Response>
<Dial callerId="+17067487754"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["tocall"]); ?></Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: hi. if have created a new TwiML app and followed steps here (https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-client/how-do-i-create-a-twiml-app) but now, whenever i press call, i get a "Call ended" message. How do i make the actual call? i am testing to call a US number.